# Please what am I missing, Am using Laravel Framework

Tags: laravel

**`Property Controller`**

```
 public function store(CreatePropertyRequest $request)
   {
    $property = Property::create($request->except(['_token', 'property_photo']));

    if($request->hasFile('property_photos')) {
        foreach($request->file('property_photos') as $photo) {
            $imageName = Storage::disk('public')->putFile('propertyImages/' . $property->id, $photo);
            PropertyPhoto::create(['property_id' => $property->id, 'filename' => $imageName]);
        }
    }
    return redirect()->route('property.index');
}
```

Property Model

```
//I have set the fillable field
public function propertyPhotos()
{
    return $this->hasMany(PropertyPhoto::class, 'property_id');
}
```

**PropertyPhoto Model**

```
class PropertyPhoto extends Model
{
//
protected $fillable = ['property_id', 'filename'];

public function property()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Property::class);
}
public function getFilenameAttribute()
{
    return 'storage/propertyImages/'. $this->property_id. '/' . $this->filename;
}
```

}

AND VIEW PAGE

```
 {!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST','action' => 'PropertyController@store',  'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}
                    {!! csrf_field() !!}

                    <div class="form-body">
                       <!-- <h3 class="card-title m-t-15">Property Information</h3> -->
                        <h3 class="box-title m-t-40">Property Details</h3>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    {!! Form::label('property_title', 'Property Title') !!}
                                    {!! Form::text('property_title', null, ['class' => 'form-control'] ) !!}

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--/span-->
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    {!! Form::label('property_category', 'Category' . '*') !!}
                                    {!! Form::select('property_category', ['sale' => 'Sale', 'rent' => 'Rent', 'lease' => 'Lease'], null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '--Choose Property Category--']) !!}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--/span-->
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    {!! Form::label('property_group', 'Property Group') !!}
                                    {!! Form::select('property_group', $propertygroups, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Property Group' ]) !!}

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--/span-->
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    {!! Form::label('property_type', 'Type') !!}
                                    {!! Form::select('property_type', [], null, ['class' =>'form-control', 'placeholder' => '---Property Type---' ] ) !!}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--/span-->
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    {!! Form::label('property_location', 'Location') !!}
                                    {!! Form::select('property_location', $locations, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Choose Location']) !!}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--/span-->
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    {!! Form::label('property_area', 'Area') !!}
                                    {!! Form::select('property_area',[], null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '---Select Area---']) !!}
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    {!! Form::label('property_busstop', 'Bus Stop') !!}
                                    {!! Form::text('property_busstop', null, ['class' =>'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Closest Bus Stop to Property']) !!}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    {!! Form::label('property_address', 'Address') !!}
                                    {!! Form::text('property_address', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Address of the Property' ]) !!}
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    {!! Form::label('property_postcode', 'Post Code') !!}
                                    {!! Form::text('property_postcode', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    {!! Form::label('property_amount', 'Currency Type') !!}
                                    {!! Form::select('property_amount',['n' => 'Naira Sign','s' => '$'], null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    {!! Form::label('property_amount', 'Amount') !!}
                                    {!! Form::text('property_amount', null, ['class' => 'form-control' ]) !!}
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    {!! Form::label('property_size', 'Size') !!}
                                    {!! Form::text('property_size', null, ['placeholder' => 'Property Size in sqr mtr','class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    {!! Form::label('property_bedrooms', 'No. of Bedrooms') !!}
                                    {!! Form::text('property_bedrooms', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    {!! Form::label('property_bathrooms', 'No. of Bathrooms') !!}
                                    {!! Form::text('property_bathrooms', null, ['class' => 'form-control' ]) !!}
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    {!! Form::label('property_toilet', 'No. of Toilet') !!}
                                    {!! Form::text('property_toilet', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    {!! Form::label('property_carpack', 'No. of Car Pack') !!}
                                    {!! Form::text('property_carpack', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    {!! Form::label('property_mode', 'Mode') !!}
                                    {!! Form::select('property_mode',['fully_furnish' => 'Fully Furnish', 'partly_furnish' => 'Partly Furnish', 'unfurnish' => 'Unfurnish'], null, ['class' => 'form-control' ]) !!}
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    {!! Form::label('property_social_medias', 'Social Media Link(s)') !!}
                                    {!! Form::text('property_social_medias', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    {!! Form::label('property_facilities', 'Facilities') !!}
                                    {!! Form::text('property_facilities', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    {!! Form::label('property_description', 'Description') !!}
                                    {!! Form::textarea('property_description', null, ['class' => 'form-control','rows' => 3 ]) !!}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                {!! Form::label('property_photos', 'Property Photo') !!}
                                {!! Form::file('property_photos', array('class' => 'form-control', 'multiple')) !!}
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-actions">
                        {!! Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-success'] ) !!}
                        <a href="{{ URL::previous() }}" class="btn btn-inverse">Go Back</a>
                    </div>

                    {!! Form::close()  !!}
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <!--Displa Error Message Here -->

        @if(count($errors) > 0)

            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <ul>
                @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>

        @endif
        <!---------End------------------>
```

DATABASE MIGRATION
for propertyphotos

```
    public function up()
    {
    Schema::create('property_photos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('property_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->string('filename');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('property_id')
            ->references('id')->on('properties')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

The problem is: When I click the submit button, the records are inserted into property table, and no record whatsover is inserted to `propertyphotos` table, nor is any path created for `property_images`, and worst is that there is no error message.

Also, in my `{!! Form::open() !!}` I included the `'files' => true`
I did change it to 'encytype' => 'multipart/form-data' and no luck.

Please, what am I missing? Is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to do? Any suggestion whatsoever would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I would use the storage class to save images, but if you don't want to do that then $destinationPath = storage_path().'/property_images/'; and php artisan storage:link also  $properties->property_photos()->create(([
                'filename' => $filename
            ]); or   $photos =  PropertyPhoto::create([ 'property_id' => $properties->id, 
                'filename' => $filename
            ]);

Comment: Thanks @Indra for your suggestion, however no luck when i tried your solution, am still inserting records to properties table and nothing is done in the property image table and still no errors, neither is their any path created. Please do you have any workable solution using storage class? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @lefman i'll read everything you wrote again and post here what I find. No worries. we'll find a solution. Edit: the issue is with the relation. Since image hasMany properties. I can't go into details until i'm off work, but i will answer later if no one post anything

Comment: I just don't know whats happening, i have tried to dd() the image and am receiving values for the image outside the if() statement, is as if the if($request(hasFile())){} is skipped. Dont just know what to do, please I need assistance on this, i have been on this issue for the past 2 days now, Any workable solution would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @Indra. would really appreciate. Thank you.

Comment: @lefman can you add the html code as well?

Comment: Again big thank you to you @Indra for getting back to me, I have tried both solution step by step but still no luck, I would update the question and paste what i have in my controller, model and view. Thank you.

Comment: try doing dd($request->all()); to see if you have any files in the request in the controller

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are using `enctype= "multipart/form-data" within form tag`

Comment: Yes am using encytype but is still the same thing

Comment: Thanks @Indra and thanks @ Lavkush Gupta,  problem solved. In my case it was because of the Form::file which i corrected. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

1. A review of what you have

You have a form where you add a property and multiple photos. It would be super helpful to know how your html looks like, but i'll just assume your input for the file  is and that you have  ...  and you have added a hidden input with csrf token and you also do some validation behind that request to make sure the files are always sent. I will also assume you don;t so this using ajax (which would change the behavior a bit)

In Property model you have a reltionshop with PropertyPhoto called property_photos (should be propertyPhotos) and is hasMany

In PropertyPhoto you have a relation with Property model and it's called propertis (shoudld be called property since is belongs to)

In PropertyController you have a method called store where you want to store all this stuff. This is how you should do it:

2. Code

In Property and PropertyPhoto model add the column you want to save to in fillable like this
In Property:

```
protected $fillable = [
'property_title', 
'property_category', 
'property_group', 
'property_type', 
'property_location', 
'property_area', 
'property_busstop', 
'property_address', 
'property_postcode', 
'property_amount', 
'property_size', 
'property_bedrooms', 
'property_bathrooms', 
'property_toilet', 
'property_carpack', 
'property_mode', 
'property_social_medias', 
'property_facilities', 
'property_description',];
```

In PropertyPhotos

```
protected $fillable = ['property_id', 'filename'];
```

This is not mandatory, but makes the code look a lot cleaner. You can skip this

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   $property = Property::create($request->except['_token', 'property_photos']);

    if($request->hasFile('property_photos')) {
        $images = [];
        foreach($request->file('property_photos') as $photo) {
           $imageName = Storage::disk('public')->putFile('propertyImages/' . $property->id, $photo);
           $images[]['filename'] = $imageName;
        }
        $property->property_images()->create($images);
    }
    return redirect()->route('property.index');
}
```

or

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   $property = Property::create($request->except['_token', 'property_photos']);

    if($request->hasFile('property_photos')) {
        foreach($request->file('property_photos') as $photo) {
           $imageName = Storage::disk('public')->putFile('propertyImages/' . $property->id, $photo);
            PropertyImages::create(['property_id' => $property->id, 'filename' => $imageName]);
        }
    }
    return redirect()->route('property.index');
}
```

in PropertyImages

This is an accessor used to get the path to the image

```
     public function getFilenameAttribute()
        {
// edit here: since filename should include that stuff. Image should be in storage/propertyImages/propertyId
            return 'storage/' . $this->filename;
        }
```

finally `php artisan storge:link`

You should save all your files in storage. Later if you work with AWS of GCloud you can use S3 or Bucket to store files at lower costs

To access the image `$propertyImage->filename;` // just like that

Comment: dd($propertyImage->filename). If $propertyImage is the variable you send to the view. Second thing: $property->propertyImage->first()->filename

Comment: {{ dd($property->propertyPhotos) }} returned an empty collection

Comment: Please how can i retrieve all the image at once, I removed the first(), but it didnt work, any suggestion. thank you.

Comment: @foreach($property->propertyPhotos as $photo) $photo->filename @endforeach